# Using RabbitMQ in Android app

Tags: android, xamarin.android, rabbitmq

I'm developing an Android realtime messaging app. Server is RabbitMQ, so I use RabbitMQ client in Android app.

Now Android services can't run "forever" in background. So my logic is start intent service, establish Rabbit connection, send/receive messages and stop service (+ close connection) after some transport inactivity - no incoming/outgoing messages ~30 seconds.
But creating a RabbbitMQ connection is very expensive and takes some time (few seconds, sometimes about 15-20 sec). This is an unacceptable delay...

So, my question is how to working with RabbitMQ in Android app? Best practices?

Comment: "Android services can't run "forever" in background" Wrong. Press play on your music player and see for yourself.

Comment: Foreground services can do that

Comment: I wonder if commiting yourself to RabbitMQ in your Android app is a good idea. Perhaps a more abstracted communication medium might be better, that way you can change your backend without needing to update all the mobile apps. You might look at the STOMP plugin which allows you to use STOMP in your Android app and RabbitMQ on your backend.

Comment: Earlier I tried to use STOMP with websockets transport. Not a good idea. In addition, this way more energy consumable ... App working slower then with native rabbitmq client.